# How can I configure Google voice access so that I only have to say "hey Google" once?

Tags: google, voice-recognition, accessibility

After I say "hey Google", [Google voice access](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess&hl=en_ZA&gl=US) is letting me say a few voice commands. However, after a few ones, I have to say "hey Google" again to be allowed to give further voice commands.

How can I configure  [Google voice access](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess&hl=en_ZA&gl=US) so that I only have to say "hey Google" once?

I did disable "time out after the speech":

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just updated the voice access application to the version 5.0.35 and the issue is fixed: there's no more timeout, i.e. voice access stays activated until one closes it.